# Custom Wordpress Loop Printing 'The Time' First

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, time

This is the [site](http://redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/test/my3DtwinAlpha/news/) I'm working on:

And my custom loop:

```
$custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=4');
if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
echo "<ul>";
while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); 

echo '<li><span class="newsorange"> &#8250;</span>
<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
' . get_the_title() . '
</a>  <br/>
<span class="newsdate">
' . the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ' 
</span>   
</li> <br/> ';  
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo "</ul>";   
endif;
```

If you look on the link you'll see it's printing the time first when I haven't asked it to do that, not sure how to fix this, any help appreciated :-]

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you haven't asked it to print the Time, yet you have `the_time('l, F jS, Y');` (which is actually a date) in your code.

Comment: Is your custom loop inside singlepost.php? If so you might still have the_time being pulled from your index.php.

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, I did have a semi-colon instead of a full stop!
It's still printing the date **before** the post title, when I am asking it to print the date **after** the title. 
Any help appreciated :-]

Comment: WBO Co. this custom loop is inside page_news.php, so it shouldn't be taking the_time from index.php?

Comment: As far as I can tell `$custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=4');` is printing the date first, I'm not sure why but I think it might be that some other bit of php is putting it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is printing the time to the page first, is because the function

```
the_time('l, F jS, Y');
```

this will output the time of the post (most commonly used in the single.php page) 
but! your wanting to use the_time() inside a loop!

What you want is: [get_the_time( $d, $post );](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_time)

if you change your code to

```
<?php
$custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=4');
if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<ul>
<?php while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); ?>
   <li style="margin-bottom:5px;">
      <span class="newsorange"> &#8250;</span>
      <a style="display:block;" href="<?php the_permalink()">
         <?php the_title();?>
      </a>
      <span class="newsdate">
         <?php echo get_the_time('l, F jS, Y', $custom_loop->ID);?>
      </span>   
   </li>
   <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

added some basic inline css styles to remove your br tags!
Also broke up your php and HTML for readability...

Marty

Answer (score 0):

; should be .

```
$custom_loop = new WP_Query('showposts=4');
if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : 
echo "<ul>";
while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); 

echo '<li><span class="newsorange"> &#8250;</span>
<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
' . get_the_title() . '
</a>  <br/>
<span class="newsdate">
' . the_time('l, F jS, Y'). ' 
</span>   
</li> <br/> ';  
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo "</ul>";   
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks RezaSh, I did copy your code in in case I missed anything.